# Bubbling NotifyOfPropertyChange with embedded classes

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

So here's a question that has me running in circles. I am working with an embedded class structure which needs to keep its child objects private but should be able to pass certain NotifyOfPropertyChange events up the ladder from data in those child objects. What is the best way to do this.

My current approach is the code below where my view for SystemViewModel (SystemView) has an element bound to the `CommunicationStatus` property, and I have a parent class SystemViewModel that has child class CommunicationManager which has child class Communicator as follows.

Things that make it difficult:

1) It MUST be assumed in this case that Communicator has no visibility of SystemViewModel so putting a `NotifyOfPropertyChanged(() => CommunicationStatus)` in the `set` method of Communicator's `Connected` property should not be an option... unless I'm missing something obvious.

2) SystemViewModel should not be able to access Communicator directly so binding from `SystemView.xaml` to `Connected` can't be done.

In my mind the NotifyOfPropertyChanged event in `Connected` should bubble up to the parents due to the implementation of `PropertyChangedBase` in all classes but that's not happening. Would love any help!

```
public class SystemViewModel : PropertyChangedBase
{
    private CommunicationManager CommunicationManager;
    public string CommunicationStatus
    {
        get
        {
            if (CommunicationManager.YepConnected)
            {
                return "Green";
            }
            else
            {
                return "Red";
            }
        }
    }
}

public class CommunicationManager : PropertyChangedBase
{
    private Communicator Communicator;
    public bool YepConnected { get { return Communicator.Connected; } }
}

public class Communicator: PropertyChangedBase
{
    private bool _connected;

    public bool Connected
    {
        get { return _connected; }
        set 
        {
            _connected = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Connected);
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

So it appears that this works correctly and propagates the event as expected from the child class to the parent class. The real issue, which was a bit more insideous, has to do with how the WPF Binding relates to the property. Just for reference, the XAML I'm using looks like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="Status" Background="{Binding CommunicationStatus}"/>
```

Also, I used `SolidColorBrush` instead of `string` (although they both bind the same and work).

The issue is that when the notification event propagates up from `Connected` to `CommunicationStatus`, it stops there and does not propagate to the XAML binding (Nowhere in my code is `CommunicationStatus` used except in the XAML binding). I know the binding works because by debug I observe that when the program runs initially the color is set to red upon execution of the `CommunicationStatus` `get` method, presumably called from the XAML binding. Once the code is running, `CommunicationStatus` does update whenever `Connected` does, but the XAML binding no longer observes that change. If I manually implement `NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => CommunicationStatus);`, the binding element decides to update. However, because I'm not using any sort of `set` method in `CommunicationStatus` (and the notify event doesn't propagate up), there doesn't seem to be a straight-forward way of informing the XAML that my value has changed.

Sketchy Solution: Watch for changes to `CommunicationStatus` and raise the `NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => CommunicationStatus);` event as follows:

```
public class SystemViewModel : Conductor<object>
{

    private CommunicationManager CommunicationManager;
    private SolidColorBrush LastCommunicationStatusValue = new SolidColorBrush();
    public SolidColorBrush CommunicationStatus
    {
        get
        {
            SolidColorBrush CurCommunicationStatusValue;
            if (CommunicationManager.YepConnected)
            {
                CurCommunicationStatusValue = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
            }
            else
            {
                CurCommunicationStatusValue = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
            }
            if (CurCommunicationStatusValue.Color != LastCommunicationStatusValue.Color)
            {
                LastCommunicationStatusValue = CurCommunicationStatusValue;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => CommunicationStatus);
            }
            return CurCommunicationStatusValue;
        }
    }
}
```

And yes, if you don't do it perfectly it's an instant Stack Overflow (pun intended :)
Whenever the value of `Connected` changes, I observe that `CommunicationStatus`'s `get` method executes. By doing this, that execution results in another execution of the `get` method, only this time the XAML updates.

Can anyone explain why this solution works and/or offer a more eloquent solution?

Comment: Very easy job with ReactiveUI

Comment: This is basic class OO theory - simply wrap or hide the properties. So you catch the notifications from the member instances, and only pass on (propagate) the ones that you specifically allow.

Comment: I guess my question then is in the mechanism of wrapping and how notifications propagate. If I wrap a property of a member instance in a `get` method, are its notifications automatically raised in the wrapper simply because it's in the wrapper? Or rather, if my get is `ParentMethod { get {Child.A*Child.B*Child.C} }`, is it true that a raised notification from either `A`, `B`, `C` will result in a raised notification in `ParentMethod`?

Comment: The answer to this question is yes. The issue was more complex. See the updated **Edit**

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example how to do that with ReactiveUI

```
public class SystemViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    private readonly CommunicationManager communicationManager;
    private readonly ObservableAsPropertyHelper<string> connectionStatus;

    public SystemViewModel( CommunicationManager communicationManager )
    {
        this.communicationManager = communicationManager ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(communicationManager));
        this.communicationManager
            .WhenAnyValue( e => e.YepConnected, state => state ? "Green" : "Red" )
            .ToProperty( this, e => e.ConnectionStatus, out connectionStatus );
    }
    public string ConnectionStatus => connectionStatus.Value;
}
```

---

```
public class CommunicationManager : ReactiveObject
{
    private readonly Communicator communicator;
    private readonly ObservableAsPropertyHelper<bool> yepConnected;

    public CommunicationManager(Communicator communicator)
    {
        this.communicator = communicator ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(communicator));
        this.communicator
            .WhenAnyValue( e => e.Connected )
            .ToProperty( this, e => e.YepConnected, out yepConnected );
    }
    public bool YepConnected => yepConnected.Value;
}
```

---

```
public class Communicator : ReactiveObject
{
    private bool _connected;
    public bool Connected
    {
        get { return _connected; }
        set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged( ref _connected, value); }
    }
}
```

Simple test

```
var communicator = new Communicator();
var manager = new CommunicationManager(communicator);
var vm = new SystemViewModel( manager );

vm.PropertyChanged += (s,e) => Console.WriteLine( "SystemViewModel.{0} changed", e.PropertyName );

communicator.Connected = true;
communicator.Connected = false;
```

generated output

```
SystemViewModel.ConnectionStatus changed
SystemViewModel.ConnectionStatus changed
```